# Laravel horizon and supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, redis, horizon

I stumbled upon a strange thing using Laravel horizon with supervisor.

I'm getting a strange infinite loop over a job which keep failing. I don't know if its my supervisor configuration that is wrong. Here you can see the horizon log.

[horizon logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER0L8.png)

My supervisor configuration is like this:

```
[program:daemon-758131]
command=php /home/forge/******/artisan horizon
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=1
startsecs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/*******/storage/logs/horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
stopsignal=SIGKILL
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

If i take a look at my supervisor status i got this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJVEG.png)

And my horizon configuration is like this in my code, (i've created a new supervisor for long running processes):

```
'environments' => [
'production' => [
    'supervisor-1' => [
        'maxProcesses' => 10,
        'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
        'balanceCooldown' => 3,
    ],
    'supervisor-long-running' => [
        'connection' => 'redis-long-running',
        'queue' => 'audio-converter',
        'balance' => 'simple',
        'processes' => 2,
        'tries' => 1,
        'timeout' => 30
    ]
],
```

And in my queue config:

```
 'redis-long-running' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'audio-converter',
            'retry_after' => 30,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],
```

This job is not even present in the laravel scheduler.

Funny thing is that i have another job for notifications and it is working good, it is not spawned like this job.

I'm getting crazy at this strange thing. Maybe someone can help me? thanks!!

I've tried to change the supervisor configuration, change the queues , flush the queues, flush redis db etc..

The job is connecting to an external API, it take around 2 min generally to complete.

Comment: From failed jobs on the horizon, can you show the error? Is it a timeout error or 500? Basically the reason for failing the job

Comment: Also, make sure you have not specified the `tries` much higher. If job fails it will retry that many times

Comment: The "supervisor status" you've shown is the status of _the supervisor process_ as viewed by _systemd_ (i.e. the next level up); it shows the tree of OS-level processes that are running, but can't tell you anything about things that failed to run. To show the status of _processes managed by supervisor_, use `supervisorctl status`; that will list all the jobs configured, including those that failed.

Comment: Also, console output and logs should generally be [included as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157957).

Comment: @IMSoP if i  use your command i get this: daemon-758131:daemon-758131_00   RUNNING   pid 237445, uptime 1:15:44

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham thanks for your input, my tries is set to 1 as you can see. Where can i see the failed jobs logs?

Comment: @ARTa This comments section is only for temporary notes, and does not support any formatting; for any additional details, please click [edit] under the original question, and just add or replace whichever parts are relevant. If you haven't already, have a look at the [tour] and [help] to understand how this site differs from a traditional forum.

Comment: @ARTa On Horizon dashboard, under the failed jobs tab you shall see the failed job entries with complete stacktrace

Comment: Supervisor settings look ok. Can you just simply skip ANY processing done in the `AudioConverter` job and use `sleep(3)` for *3* seconds and test *both* queues, as in the `default` and the `audio-converter` and see if it fails and if so, when. Also give the `AudioConverter` job a [timeout](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#timeout) of `public $timeout = 6;` seconds and [max](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#max-attempts) attempts `public $tries = 1;` of 1 so it doesn't go into a loop.